# I have complex JSON data and I need to create an HTML form to easily edit it. Quickest approach?

Tags: json, html, forms

I can't exactly predict what shape my JSON data will be in, so I would like to take an approach where my JSON is fed into an HTML-form-generator of some kind.  I don't need an overly slick approach and don't mind programming one myself.  Just wondering if there are any tools or patterns that people know of.

The form will end up being in a Meteor app and the JSON it is editing will be directly backed up by a MongoDB document, so I basically want to generate HTML forms to edit arbitrary MongoDB documents.  I'd like the ability to highly customize it to the specific documents I have in mind, however.

Answer (score 0):

I found [Schema Form](http://schemaform.io/) quite interesting. It is a set of AngularJS directives to generate Bootstrap 3 ready forms from a JSON Schema. [Here](http://schemaform.io/examples/bootstrap-example.html) is one working example for the same. Not sure if it entirely suits your purpose but it looks quite promising to me. You can even [fork](https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form) it and tweak it for your purpose. Have a look!

Hope it helps!